# How to use Mockito to show all invocations on a mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, debugging, junit, mockito

I have a unit test that is failing and I'm unsure why. I want to be able to see all invocations on the mock that occur in the System Under Test. This is not the behavior that I want for all tests always, simply for a test that I need to quickly tweak to be able to figure out what's wrong.

However, it seems kind of like a hack. **Is it possible to do this natively in Mockito, without having to use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`**?

This is not preferred, because the stack trace includes all the other invocations used internally by Mockito.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This feature is builtin since Mockito 1.9.5. Just use

```
mock(ClassToMock.class, withSettings().verboseLogging())
```

Answer (score 19):

From Mockito 2.2.6 you can inspect a mock with [`MockingDetails Mockito.mockingDetails(Object mockToInspect)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.6/org/mockito/MockingDetails.html).

You can either dig into the `MockingDetails` properties by invoking : `getMock()`, `getStubbings()`, `getInvocations()` and so for ... or simply use the `printInvocations()` method that returns :

> a printing-friendly list of the invocations that occurred with the mock
> object. Additionally, this method prints stubbing information,
> including unused stubbings. For more information about unused stubbing
> detection see MockitoHint.

For example with JUnit 5 :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FooTest {

    Foo foo;

    @Mock
    Bar bar;

    @Test
    void doThat() throws Exception {
        
        Mockito.when(bar.getValue())
               .thenReturn(1000L);          

        // ACTION
        foo.doThat();

        // ASSERTION
        // ...

        // add that to debug the bar mock           
        System.out.println(mockingDetails(bar).printInvocations());
    }
}
```

And you get an output such as :

```
[Mockito] Interactions of: Mock for Bar, hashCode: 962287291
 1. bar.getValue();
  -> at Foo.doThat() (Foo.java:15) 
   - stubbed -> at FooTest.doThat(FooTest.java:18)
```

Note that the classes with a referenced line in the output are links to your source code/test class.  Very practical.

Comment: [printInvocations](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/MockingDetails.html#printInvocations()) was added in `2.2.6`