# Showing Interactions with @MockBean Annotated Mock

Tags: spring, testing, mockito

In Spring applications one can write tests with mocked beans which are autowired by default and which can be further customised with the usual Mockito methods. For this, the @MockedBean annotation is used.
However, when using just Mockito without Spring, one can configure the mocks to print all interactions, see [How to use Mockito to show all invocations on a mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294277/how-to-use-mockito-to-show-all-invocations-on-a-mock).
Is this debugging also possible with mocked beans?

Answer (score 3):

There is no Sprint native way, but one can use the `mockingDetails(<some mock>)` Method from Mockito to retrieve the `MockingDetails` of the mock and then print the interactions. Put the debugging in an @After annotated method to show it every time, even when the test fails.

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mockingDetails;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
public class MyTest {
    @MockBean
    LoginDAO loginDaoMock;

    @Test
    public void xyz()  {
    // some test
    }

    @After
    public void showInteractions() {
        System.out.println(mockingDetails(loginDaoMock).getInvocations());
    }
}
```