# Mockito mock invocation points point to Junit code (ParentRunner)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Never saw this problem before - when using `verify` or `verifyInteractions` and the test fails, Mockito's list of onvocations points to JUnit code and not application code:

```java
[junit] No interactions wanted here:
[junit] -> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
[junit] But found this interaction on mock 'mockCounter':
[junit] -> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
[junit] ***
[junit] For your reference, here is the list of all invocations ([?] - means unverified).
[junit] 1. [?]-> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
[junit] 2. [?]-> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
[junit] 3. -> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
[junit]
[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:
[junit] No interactions wanted here:
[junit] But found this interaction on mock 'mockCounter':
[junit] ***
[junit] For your reference, here is the list of all invocations ([?] - means unverified).
```

I am using Mockito `1.10.19` and JUnit `4.12`. The code is pretty standard:

```java
public class MyTest {
    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Mock
    private Counter mockCounter;

...

    @Test
    public void test() {
       ...
       verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockCounter);
    }
```

First I was also using `ExpectedException` rule:

```java
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();
```

...which caused additional problems, because it caught Mockito's verification failure as an unexpected exception:

```
[junit] No interactions wanted here:
[junit] -> at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
[junit] But found this interaction on mock 'mockCounter':
[junit] -> at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
[junit] ***
[junit] For your reference, here is the list of all invocations ([?] - means unverified).
[junit] 1. [?]-> at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
[junit] 2. [?]-> at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
[junit] 3. -> at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
[junit]
[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:
[junit] No interactions wanted here:
[junit] But found this interaction on mock 'mockCounter':
[junit] ***
[junit] For your reference, here is the list of all invocations ([?] - means unverified).
```

I am working on a new code base and never seen this problem before. It seems like either Mockito or JUnit clean up stack traces too aggressively or something...

I can live without `ExpectedException` but it seems pretty annoying to not have mock invocation points in case of future test failures. How can I fix this? I [saw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26426215/49678) the notion of `withSettings().verboseLogging()` but I don't want to log invocations at all times, only if the test fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `MockitoRule` is the culprit. Replacing it with `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` in `setUp()` method fixes the problem completely, even when `ExpectedException` rule is used.

It has been [fixed](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/344) in Mockito `2.x` but not back-ported to `1.x`.